# Where do I place str_replace(' ', '-', to remove spaces from url and load proper sql data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, url

I am able to add dashes to the url with the help from previous post  but, I can not get the proper page to load once i complete this task.

A portion of the php code:

```
$query_getDisplay = sprintf("SELECT blog.title, blog.description, blog.keywords,
blog.blog_entry,  DATE_FORMAT(blog.updated, '%%M %%e, %%Y') AS formatted, 
blog.blogphoto FROM blog WHERE blog.category = 'videos'
AND DATE_FORMAT(blog.updated, '%%Y-%%m') = %s
ORDER BY blog.updated DESC", GetSQLValueString($var1_getDisplay2, "text"));

} elseif (isset($_GET['title'])) {
  $var2_getDisplay3 = $_GET['title'];

$query_getDisplay = sprintf("SELECT blog.title,blog.description, blog.keywords,
blog.blog_entry,  DATE_FORMAT(blog.updated, '%%M %%e, %%Y') AS formatted,
blog.blogphoto FROM blog WHERE blog.title = %s",
GetSQLValueString($var2_getDisplay3, "text"));

} else {

$query_getDisplay = "SELECT blog.title, blog.blog_entry, blog.description,
blog.keywords,  DATE_FORMAT(blog.updated, '%M %e, %Y') AS formatted,
blog.blogphoto FROM blog WHERE blog.category = 'videos' ORDER BY blog.updated DESC
LIMIT 2";

}

$getDisplay = mysql_query($query_getDisplay, $check_mag) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getDisplay = mysql_fetch_assoc($getDisplay);
$totalRows_getDisplay = mysql_num_rows($getDisplay);
?>
```

URL works properly code shown below

```
    <div id="recent">
      <h3>Recent Post</h3>
<ul>
        <?php do { ?>
          <li><a href="videos.php?title=<?php echo str_replace(' ',
             '-',$row_getRecent['title']); ?>"
             ><?php echo $row_getRecent['title']; ?></a></li>
          <?php } while ($row_getRecent = mysql_fetch_assoc($getRecent)); ?>
<li> <a></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you want to do? You said that url works properly, then what is the issue?

Comment: You know, sprintf() is massive overkill when `$x = "abc $d efg"` would work just as well. sprintf() is only useful if you need to format (zero-pad, limit decimals, etc...) the values you're inserting.

Comment: The problem I am having is getting the page to load when str_replace(' ',
             '-', is used.  There is a problem with the SQL portion because the page show no content, but it shows the correct url.  If it helps the website is www.jmoneyproductions.com

Comment: newbie to coding the sprintf() was created by dreamweaverCS5,  thanks for the advise I will test the example that you provided me with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am not sure why you want to run `str_replace` on `URL` but i guess you want proper Url encoding .. you should try `urlencode` http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php instead

```
urlencode($row_getRecent['title']);
```

Comment: Thank you I was trying to do more than needed